# Toggling the state of a checkbox by clicking its parent element

Tags: jquery, html

I have a checkbox inside a table cell and I want to check it when I click on my cell (not only when I click on checkbox).

I'm using this code:

```
$('.check_it').click( function () {
    if ($(this).find('.my_checkbox_class').is(':checked')) {
        $(this).find('.my_checkbox_class').removeAttr('checked');
        checked_counter--;
    }
    else {
        $(this).find('.my_checkbox_class').attr('checked', 'checked');
        checked_counter++;
    }
});
```

It works fine, but when I'm clicking on my checkbox, this event gets fired too and my `checked_counter` variable gets wrong value - can someone tell me how to fix it?
I want to check checkbox by clicking it and by clicking it's table cell.

Edit, here is my html:

```
<td class="check_it"><input type="checkbox" class="my_checkbox_class" /></td>
```

Comment: can you post your html?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why is it necessary for you to keep a `checked_counter`? The `checked` property of the element itself can provide you with that information...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.my_checkbox_class').click(function(ev){
    ev.stopPropagation();
});
```

Should do the trick. This stops the event from bubbling up so it doesn't reach the td and only the checkbox default behavior gets executed.

Answer (score 2):

Click events are propagated up the DOM tree to parent elements. When you click on the checkbox, it therefore also triggers the event on the `<td>`. You can get around this by catching the event at the checkbox and stopping propagation there (which adds a second event handler, and may also break other functionality relying on the event bubbling).

The alternative method, which I recommend, is checking the origin of the event before doing your toggling, within the same handler. This makes use of the [jQuery event object](http://api.jquery.com/event.Target/)'s `target` property.

```
$('td').click(function(e)
{
    if ( $(e.target).is('[type="checkbox"]') ) return;

    var $chkBox = $(this).find('.my_checkbox_class');
    var state = $chkBox.is(':checked');
    checked_counter += (state ? -1 : 1);
    $chkBox.prop('checked', !state);
});
```

Note, I also refactored your original click handler, since all your are really doing is toggling the state of the checkbox (for which you should use [`prop`](http://api.jquery.com/prop)). This *replaces* your current handler, it is not in addition to is.

Answer (score 0):

use `$(".my_checkbox_class").click(function() {}`

as per your code `$('check_it').click(function() {}` this may have chechbox as well as row details so that this function is calling on both cases this leads wring behavior.